# How to access the (firestore) document id or adress in typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a functions which will send to all the devices where an user is logged in once a new order document has been added in his account.

This is my code to run the function. My question is how to access the {userEmail}/{orderId} from the document.

```
export const orderUserNotif = functions.firestore
    .document('userAccounts/{userEmail}/orders/{orderId}')
    .onCreate(async snapshot => {

        const order = snapshot.data();

        const querySnapshot = await db
            .collection('userAccounts')
            .doc("{userEmail}") //Want to access the userEmail from the document address
            .collection('tokens')
            .get();

        const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);

        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
                title: order!.title + " with ID " + '{orderId}', //Want to access order id here
                body: `Your order has been shipped`,
            }
        };

        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the values from the path that triggered the Cloud Function with `context.params`. The `context` is passed as a second parameter to your Cloud Function, but you don't yet declare it.

So something like this:

```
export const orderUserNotif = functions.firestore
    .document('userAccounts/{userEmail}/orders/{orderId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

        const order = snapshot.data();

        const querySnapshot = await db
            .collection('userAccounts')
            .doc(context.params.userEmail)
            .collection('tokens')
            .get();

        const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);

        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
                title: order!.title + " with ID " + context.params.orderId,
                body: "Your order has been shipped",
            }
        };

        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    })
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [specifying a group of documents using wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).